How to replace HTML with dynamically generated content containing the JS let keyword?
I am currently going through older projects and upgrading them use jQuery 3.7. Many of the web pages use AJAX to dynamically generate and render HTML pages through Flask. The AJAX worked previously without any issues. However, after upgrading to jQuery 3.7, I am having issues rendering the content when the template contains JavaScript with the let keyword.
Python
from flask import Flask, render_template    
app = Flask(__name__)    

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('test.html')    

@app.route('/dynamic')
def dynamic_content():
    return render_template('dynamic.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

test.html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Hello World!</div>
<button onclick="return loadContent();">
    Load Content
</button>
<script>
    function loadContent() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dynamic',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                $("#content").html(response)
            }
        })
    }
</script>

dynamic.html
My dynamic content
<script>
    let test = 1;
</script>

When loadContent is called the first time, it dynamically generates and displays the HTML onto the web page. When it is called a second time, it gets the JavaScript error

Identifier 'test' has already been declared

I know what this error means and the scope of let, but as stated previously, doing this previously worked without errors. It seems like even if the form is being replaced with dynamically generated content, jQuery 3.7 seems to have issues knowing that JavaScript variables declared with let are also being re-defined.
Is there any way around this issue, and allow jQuery to replace the dynamic content with the let keyword?

The old behavior was wrong, now it's correct. It's evaluating the code in the global scope, and you can only declare a variable with let once in any scope.

What version are you updating from? If it's not too old, you can make a diff to see what changed in how it emulates <script> tags in .html().

This behavior seems pretty logical. Is the <script> part also dynamic? If not, is it possible to extract the scripts from the html file and put them into a separate js file?

Note: every version of jQuery from 3.0 and up produces the same behavior.

@Barmar I'd have to check the history, but (as JonSG kind of pointed out) the upgrade is from v2.9. So not sure how feasible it would be to emulate that

A solution might be to declare the variable test in the test.html e.g. let test; and then you can just update it in the dynamic script instead of declaring it again, e.g. test = 1;

@Rob I thought about going down that direction as well, but was hoping there would've been a solution without that much code change

I'm not sure, but I suspect this commit may be related to the changed behavior: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6680c1b29ea79bf33ac6bd31578755c7c514ed3e
